# module not found error Bio in miniconda environment

Tags: python, pip, bioinformatics, biopython, miniconda

I installed bio python as

`pip install biopython` as well as `conda install -c conda-forge biopython`. I see in site-packages. for some reason there is `Bio` dependency. How do I resolve this dependency?

```
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bio
>>> bio.__version__
'1.75'
>>> from bio import pairwise2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bio/pairwise2.py", line 246, in <module>
    from Bio import BiopythonWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
>>>
```

Comment: the normal way to import biopython is via `import Bio` not `import bio`- I'm actually not sure how you managed to get the lower case version installed??

Comment: I suggest you uninstall all biopython versions and re-install via one only (i prefer `pip`). Then you should do `import Bio; Bio.__version__`

Comment: @Chris_Rands what are the installation instructions?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yeah this solution does not work. that has been tried. the package has issues because I do not see the package in the `sitepackages` folder. I do see `bio, biopython`, etc but do not see `Bio or Bio.py or Bio` object.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong here- your installations are all mixed up. `import bio` should fail! There should only be `site-packages/Bio` (and `site-packages/BioSQL`) not `site-packages/biopython` or `site-packages/bio`. Conda doesn't even offer biopython version 1.75 yet either! All I can recommend is a fresh install as i said

Comment: No my installation is alright. when it downloads packages as bio and puts in site packages, the folder has been named as bio instead of Bio. see my answer below.

Comment: tried both `conda` and `pip`

Comment: It looks like you did something weird manually like re-name the folders, otherwise there is a bug to fix, but you haven't given enough information to reproduce your error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203242/discussion-between-lpt-and-chris-rands).

Comment: try uninstalling your package and then doing pip or conda to check if you get `bio` in site packages?

Comment: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/2363

Comment: Looks like a side effect of https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3309 on Windows (or any case insensitive file system), we need our folder under site-packages to be Bio not bio.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, renaming `bio` as `Bio` in `sitepackages` then it works

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Bio
>>> from Bio import pairwise2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched on google how to install biopython using pip in this [link](https://pypi.org/project/biopython/).

1. You need to type `pip install biopython`or `pip install biopython --user`
2. Then import Bio(it is with B not b)

```py
import Bio
print(Bio.__version__)
```

I'm sure documentation is always a good start which you can find [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc4).