# Biopython is successfully installed in anaconda 3 but the module fails to be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython, anaconda3

A variation of this problem was asked before but I'm forced to ask because the solutions given there didn't work for me.

I'm using Jupyter in anaconda 3. First I installed biopython using `!pip install biopython`. It was successfully installed but when I tied to `import Bio' it returned a ModuleNotFoundError.

Later I used `conda install -c anaconda jupyter` and `conda install -c anaconda biopython` in the anaconda prompt to install biopython. They were successfully installed but the same problem remains.

However, if I type `import bio' with a small b then the module error doesn't show up. However, I still can't call any function within the module. Here is an example of the error I'm facing. This is my very first post so I don't have enough reputation to post embed images. I will post external links here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew0sQ.jpg

So I checked if the directory had the folder name with uppercase or lowercase. It was uppercase, so I thought maybe it should be changed to lowercase and I changed. Still the same problem.

Here is my PATH and it seems to include the anaconda directory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKhxz.jpg

I really need to use biopython, so please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module not found error Bio in miniconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080862/module-not-found-error-bio-in-miniconda-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Bio is the correct reference to use.

Try this:
First ensure the name of the package folder is Bio as this is the correct name

```
dir C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\*io*
...
06/10/2020  01:12 PM    <DIR>          Bio
...
```

Then try this code:

```
import Bio
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

f=open('smn.fasta').read()
result=NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn","nt",f)
```

Comment: Somehow Bio cannot be imported, but bio can. Trying to import Bio returns a Module error.

Comment: after the changes you made earlier, can you check if the package is currently named "bio" or "Bio" in this directory? `dir path_to_conda\envs\test_bio\Lib\site-packages\*io*`. It should be upper case to work correctly. All the references inside the files have "Bio" not "bio".

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I changed the name in the ```C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\pkgs\biopython-1.76-py37he774522_0\Lib\site-packages\``` directory because it was the only folder named 'Bio' shown in the search result. Now it works fine.

Comment: another way to show this is to look at dir(module_name) after you import it. In my installation, this is what i see:  `import Bio`  `dir(Bio)` `['BiopythonDeprecationWarning', 'BiopythonExperimentalWarning'...` all of which is uppercased Bio

Comment: i updated my answer above to show the full fix path. Can you verify and accept my changes if they are correct?

Comment: I actually had to made my change in the following dir: C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Comment: @SafatHossain FYI, this is a windows-specific problem- at some point you did `pip install bio`, installing another package that caused this issue https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/2363

Comment: @Chris_Rands If I reinstall Conda, how should I install this package? Directly through Conda prompt?

Comment: @SafatHossain make sure you install `pip uninstall bio` and `pip uninstall biopython` (or might be `pip3`) then you can re-install via pip or from conda forge, see the official biopython website